# С#. Получить handle, присвоенный процессу операционной системой при запуске, средствами WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi

Доброго времени суток.

Возник такой вопрос. Класс System.Diagnostics.Process возвращает дескриптор процесса, присвоенный ему ОС при запуске. И вот что-то никак не могу найти способ получить его с помощью WinAPI. 
OpenProcess - возвращает, конечно, дескриптор, но, насколько понимаю, уже "свой",а не тот, который был присвоен при запуске программы.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь использовать OpenProcess, если у вас на руках нету `dwProcessId`?

Comment: @VladD Смысл "задачи" - сделать некий аналог класса Process, но с несколько расширенным функционалом и информацией )) Почти все нарыл, что для счастья нужно было, id-к или пользователь дает или через EnumProcesses - для всех процессов.

Comment: @VladD Но вот, единственно, ну никак не могу найти, где взять этот handle процесса, который бы совпадал с Process.Handle в классе .Net))

Comment: ну, стандартный `Process` начинает работу с `CreateProcess`, и у него сразу есть Id. А как вы собираетесь работать с процессами? Покажите предполагаемый код.

Comment: Это тот хэндл, который вам возвращает CreateProcess, по сути.

Comment: @VladD Угу... Все бы ничего, да Net-овская Process.GetProcesses() - возвращает список всех процессов, которые она не создавала, и у них таки handle есть. Вот и пытаюсь вкурить, где она их добывает)) По правде сказать, для работы-то оно мне и не очень надо, допустим, для GetModuleFileNameEx (модули процесса), можно получит хендл через OpenProcess. Он будет "равнозначный" и тоже "указывать" на этот процесс... Просто понять очень хоца, откуда .Net берет handle, которые, по MSDN-у: присвоены процессу операционной системой при запуске.

Comment: Ну так и правда можно ж подсмотреть в исходники. Есть замечательный сайт http://sourceof.net. Там находим метод [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,6b1f2f5b1c65e3d2), идём по ссылкам, и видим, что вся работа делается [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,fd7a197a08dd5662) через `PERF_COUNTER`.

Comment: Handle - это идентификатор уникальный в рамках процесса, а не системы, вы их можете получить сколько угодно вызывая OpenProcess для одного и того же PID, тут всё как с файлом.

Comment: В общем нет никакого "своего" handle у процесса, только PID.

Comment: @VlaD, Primus Singularis - ага, спасибо большое, господа...  Просветился. Handle и там через Open получаютм. И элементарный эксперимент: два раза Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle - даёт два разных значения, три раза - три разных и т.д.))

Comment: @Texnic: Хэндл — да, он каждый раз свой. Хэндл по сути просто указатель на какую-то внутреннюю структуру данных, описывающую процесс. А вот processId должен быть один и тот же всегда.

Comment: @VlaD, спасибо) Кстати, тут как-то комментарии можно "засчитать за ответ" или хотя бы "плюсы" за них поставить?)

Comment: Плюс можно) Сейчас опубликую всё как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего подсмотреть в исходники. Есть замечательный сайт http://sourceof.net. Для вновь созданных процессов processId приходит из `CreateProcess`. Для `GetProcesses` сложнее. Находим метод [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,6b1f2f5b1c65e3d2), идём по ссылкам, и видим, что вся работа делается [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,fd7a197a08dd5662) через `PERF_COUNTER`.

---

Хэндл — да, он каждый раз свой. Хэндл по сути просто указатель на какую-то внутреннюю структуру данных, описывающую процесс. А вот processId должен быть один и тот же всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Свой процесс: [GetCurrentProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) из kernel32.
Чужие процессы: [EnumProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx).

И вообще: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684865(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Ага, благодарю. Да только это для текущего процесса. Я, видимо, сглупа не уточнил, что подразумевался любой процесс в системе.

Comment: @Texnic, тогда я не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Нда... Прошу прощения, когда задавал вопрос, надо было все-таки "исповедаться", а то, действительно, много недоразумений. Смысл такой (и интерес, если честно, больше все-таки "академический"):  Process.GetProcesses() возвращает список всех процессов в системе, у каждого есть handle, который, по описанию этого св-ва в MSDN: присвоен процессу операционной системой при запуске. Что, в общем-то, логично, ось при запуске его присваивает, да никак не пойму, откуда .Net его считывает...

Comment: @Texnic, обновил ответ.

Comment: Вообще-то, GetCurrentProcess возвращает константу :)

Answer (score 0):

0) сейчас у .NET есть исходный код. если бы не было то ildasm, SAI и рефлектор в помощь. да я понимаю вы никогда не колупали код и не декомпилили. но неужели так сложно догадаться в НОВОЙ ситуации применить новую тактику, похоже у вас просто синдром утенка и шаблонность мышления

1) А по теме, CreateProcess же возвращает структуру в ней и PID, только не returnом а указателем

2) В крайнем случае непонятно почему не пришел в голову костыль типа сперва запустить затем вызывать какой-нибудь EnumProcesses или другую известную функцию дающую PID

Comment: Спс)) Но, 1 - CreateProcess возвращает, когда сам запускаешь процесс, а я подразумевал любой "сторонний", 2 - EnumProcesses возвращает массив с PID-ми, а мне бы хендл (опять же, можно по этому PID исп.  OpenProcess, но хендл будет не тот, который Windows при запуске назначила) 0 - что же, как последний вариант, если другого не останется))

Comment: @Texnic с какого хрена у вас 0  последний вариант? это нормальная и даже очень полезная практика - исследовать потроха того на чем пишешь, для нормальных людей это еще и интересно, хотя таким как вы видимо не понять.

Comment: @KG: Ну вы бы как-то повежливее что ли, мы ж тут культурно общаемся без наездов и перехода на личности.

Comment: @K G, первоочередная задача у меня была - понять, почему это именно так, а не иначе. А из исходного кода это не совсем ясно) Ну, скажем так - скопипастить оттуда, конечно, можно, это решит задачу, но не очень прояснит ситуацию)) Но, в любом случае, благодарю, тем более, что, вероятно вопрос несколько неверно сформулировал, т.к. из вопроса скорее следует "как это сделать", а не "как это надо делать и почему так" )

Comment: @VladD "угу, у нас же блат культурный форум, у нас дохвоста культуры, у нас на каждом ежином шагу культура! и там у нас культура и наездов нету, и вон там тоже наездов нету, и вон там наездов нету (злобно минусуя чей-то пост), и вон там..."

Comment: @Texnic не скопипастить, а проанализировать

Comment: @KG: Ну, минус — это нормальное выражение несогласия. Комментарий с конструктивной критикой — это хорошее выражение несогласия. А переход на личности — плохое выражение несогласия.

Comment: @VladD а как мне еще объяснить проблему человеку, если она лежит  именно в его личности? по-вашему не бывает глупых людей с синдромом утенка и шаблонным мышлением? они бывают, и надо стараться им это объяснить. конечно это почти что бесполезно, они не послушают и не побегут менять свою жизнь, но временный эффект от пинка возможен, а это может помочь

Comment: @KG: Ну, я обычно не берусь судить о людях плохо, я могу ведь и ошибиться, и обидеть человека ни за что ни про что. Я придерживаюсь принципа, что «иногда лучше жевать, чем говорить» (ц)

Comment: @VladD лично я не обижусь, если меня обзовут тем кем я не являюсь

Comment: @KG: Ну вот вы не обидчивый, а другие вполне могут быть. Я сталкивался с разными людьми.